# IBM Watson Assistant: Retrieve a specific conversation via IBM Cloud Functions

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions

How can I extract a specific user conversation from all chat logs? I noticed that the chat-log JSON response contains a field named `conversation-id`.
My goal is to obtain, via Cloud Function, that specific conversation id for the current conversation. So, when the conversation starts how can I retrieve the current conversation id?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601154/ibm-watson-assistant-how-can-skill-gain-access-to-session-id-using-v2-of-wa-api/55612825#55612825):
You can access context variables using either `context[variableName]` or `$variableName`. See the [documentation on expressions for accessing objects in IBM Watson Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601154/ibm-watson-assistant-how-can-skill-gain-access-to-session-id-using-v2-of-wa-api/55612825#55612825).

The **conversation_id** is in the set of context variables (`context.conversation_id`). You can access it as part of that structure.